# How to remove an element in double nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on mongo, in this time in need to remove a specific element from array nested in another one, the structure is like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e616314946b6d3ac4ed8252"), 
    "uid" : "5db069478556622b4a0adca5", 
    "areas" : [
        {
            "name" : "mexico", 
            "elements" : [
                "23452345", 
                "24454675"
            ], 
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "usa", 
            "elemets" : [
                "123123123", 
                "1234334"
            ], 
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need a query that lets me remove any element in "elements" property.

I tried with this query but I couldn't reach it.

```
db.areas.update(
    { },
    { $pull: 
        { areas: { 
            $elemMatch: { 
                elements: { $eq : "123123123" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { multi:false }
);
```

This just said

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Comment: Replace `areas:` by `"areas.$[]:"`

Comment: `elements: { $eq : "123123123" }` you can shortcut to `elements: "123123123"`

Comment: The input documents you have posted has some inconsistency; the sub-array field `elements` is different for the `name: "usa"`; it says `elemets`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `update` for removing the specific array element in a sub-array (`elements`).

Note that to remove (*pull*) the specified element (`elements` value  `"24454675"`), you need to specify the outer-array's element matching condition (note that there are two elements in the outer-array field `areas`).

```
db.areas.update(
   { "areas.name": "mexico" },
   { $pull: { "areas.$.elements":  "24454675" } }
)
```

NOTE: If you don't specify the `{ "areas.name": "mexico" }` condition, the whole sub-document of the `areas` array will be removed.

Comment: I've been trying to pull `areas.elements` but it keeps showing errmsg.  It was `areas.$.elements`. Thanks for the answer!